# Share image to SMS, Mail, Save Image with UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, xcode, email, sms, share

I want to share image to SMS, Mail and Save Image with UIDocumentInteractionController.  just social apps to shared image.

```
self.documentationInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
[self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Can you help me ?

Thank You !

Comment: `UIDocumentInteractionController` is not for sharing to social networks for this you might use [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/)

Comment: Ok, but my image can't be shared on WhatsApp :-/

Comment: I create a custom UIActivity to share image with WhatsApp. Thank You